# Proxy Apache to Payara on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, proxy

I have an apache instance and a payara server with a deployed application on ":8080/app-name". I'm trying to proxy the root  of the website to this port and app. My config is as follows:

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
  LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyRequests Off
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app-name
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app-name
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when I try to go to `example.com` I am redirected to `example.com//` and nothing is shown.

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not included any logs, I can only guess and give you a few pointers. Please update your questions with details from Apache's error logs.

```
# TLS VHost on Port 80? - move to 443.
# Needs
## Listen *:443 https
# as well.
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Move LoadModule directives away from VHost configs.
  LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
  LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyRequests Off
  # TLS VHosts need TLS directives too - they're missing
  SSLProxyEngine On 
  ServerName site-name.com
  ServerAlias www.site-name.com
  # Use trailing slashes on downstream host URLs
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app-name/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app-name/
</VirtualHost>
```

Have a look on docs how to configure TLS correctly: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/ssl/ssl_howto.html, https://bettercrypto.org/static/applied-crypto-hardening.pdf.

Add permissions to allow access:

```
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/app-name/>
  Require all granted
</Proxy>
```

Adjust SELinux:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_relay=1
```